# iOS Second Developer Certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, provisioning-profile

My situation is that I have just hired a second developer to work remotely. He doesn't have a developer account and would like to send me his progress.

At the moment he is using my Apple Developer account with a temporary password but this is not ideal, is there a way that he can have a certificate and I can reset my password?

My Apple developer account is set up as individual by the way

Thanks

Comment: You can ask him to make an apple id and you can add him as a team agent in your developer account. He will get a invitation on his apple id. Then you can reset your password

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari please read his question and see "My Apple developer account is set up as individual by the way"... And you can't add team member in individual you only can in company one.

Comment: oh... sorry about that. You are right. I haven't read that part.

Comment: Is it possible to change to an organisation?

Comment: Individuals can be changed to company ones

Answer (score 0):

If you are not going to extensively adding and removing the devices then the easiest way is to add all the devices, create dev and distribution profiles and certificate download all in your Xcode then simply [export](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-accounts_preferences/articles/export_signing_assets.html) and send to him and he can simply [import](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-accounts_preferences/articles/import_signing_assets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013306-CH9-SW1) and use the local signing assists option not the online account .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can export the certificate and the private key for the certificate in the Keychain Access application.  You could then send the developer the key, certificate, and the provisioning profile to the other developer, who could then build the app with your provisioning profiles, without direct access to your developer account.

This will be a bit of a hassle if the other developer needs to do a lot of device maintenance on the developer profile (adding / removing devices).  If that's not the case, I would simply send him the necessary files and reset your password to prevent having to share full access to the account.